# Mongoose findOne never returns

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been having issues with mongo(specifically mongoose) not returning at all when using findOne, find or anything else.

I'm using mongoose 3.8.12

Mongodb 3.6.3

node 8.10.0

ubuntu 16.04

droplet on digitalocean

I've modified the mongoose example to be pretty well as easy as it can be and it just wont return period.

Its doing the same thing on my application so I tried to make a dead simple mongo test.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

const kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save()

Cat.findOne({}, function(err, kitten) {
    if(err){
        console.log('Error');
        return;
    }
    if(kitten){
        console.log(kitten)
    }else{
        console.log('No Kitten here')
    }
})
```

I've tested the mongo install with Robo3t and it works without issue.

Any idea where I can start looking?

Comment: Does it return anything when you run db.cats.findOne() from mongo shell or Robo3t? Have you checked if your connection to mongodb from this code is done successfully?

Comment: it returns null since the save didn't work.  console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); returns 2

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it just stays in the connecting state but never actually connects.  Any ideas what to look at?

Comment: Check mongodb logs to see if your app actually goes there and makes any connection

Comment: 2018-03-25T19:08:58.849+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.
0.0.1:51168 #91 (1 connection now open)

Comment: logs have that 5 times. Looks like its making 5 connections each time I launch the app

Comment: Ok, I don't have an answer to what happened but I fixed it inside another directory by reinstalling everything. Something must not have gone right on the last install.

Comment: Turns out its something wrong with node 8.10 and mongoose 3.8.12.   Works find with mongoose 5.11

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you might be missing 'return' like

```
if(kitten){
   console.log(kitten);
   return kitten;
}else{
   console.log('No Kitten here')
   return;
}
```

Comment: Why would they need to explicitly return at the end of a function?